# SignalR with Certificates

Tags: c#, ssl, signalr, ssl-certificate, owin

I want to create a simple SignalR application.
Using http everything works fine, but when i try to use https and certificates the application don't work.

For now, the only thing i want to do is get the Client's Certificate in the server.

**Server** (Authentication Handler):

```
 public class ClientCertificateAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<ClientCertificateAuthenticationOptions>
{
    protected override Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
    {
        var cert = Context.Get<X509Certificate>("ssl.ClientCertificate");

        if (cert == null)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<AuthenticationTicket>(null);
        }

        try
        {
            Options.Validator.Validate(cert);
        }
        catch
        {
            return Task.FromResult<AuthenticationTicket>(null);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Client** (Hub)

```
var connection = new HubConnection("https://localhost:8080/");
connection.AddClientCertificate(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("c1.cer"));
IHubProxy myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
connection.Start().Wait();
```

Doing this, in the server when i do `var cert = Context.Get<X509Certificate>("ssl.ClientCertificate");` i get `null`.

So, what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also have to tell IIS to use the client certificate. In `web.config` do:

```
<location path="signalr">
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert" />
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```

my working code

```
var cert = ServiceCallHelper.GetClientCertificate();
var url = new Uri(Settings.CoreUrl);
var str = String.Format("https://{0}/cert_signalr", url.Host);
var hub = new HubConnection(str, false);
hub.AddClientCertificate(cert);
```

and

```
object cert = null;
if (!hub.Context.Request.Environment.TryGetValue("ssl.ClientCertificate", out cert) ||
   !(cert is X509Certificate2))
{
   s_logger.WarnFormat("Hub {0} called without certificate or cookie", hub.Context.Request.ToString());
   throw new Exception("not authenticated");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I put the configurations in my App.config, but the result was the same.

Comment: I already tried that. But still not working. Could be something in the rest of the code, but i can't figure out what.

Comment: Do you have some sample of SignalR with certificates?

Comment: i think a .cer file doesnt have private key. check boolean HasPrivateKey on the cert after you load it with CreateFromCertFile

Comment: I am battling through trying to get this working but when I add the "location" to my web.config. The IIS site no longer works with the error below. Any ideas?

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

Comment: I ended getting this to work by unlocking the section like this:
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config -section:access

Also, another piece of code changed this value which was keeping the SSL/TLS protocol from completing the handshaking. So watch out:

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol